# Can you use an AppContainer to sandbox winapi processes?

Tags: windows, winapi, appcontainer

Windows 8 introduced AppContainers to sandbox Windows Store Apps. Is there a public API in Windows 8 or 10 that allows you to sandbox arbitrary processes, not just store apps?

Comment: https://github.com/MalwareTech/AppContainerSandbox

Comment: Cheers @RbMm I hadn't been able to find any examples and the documentation for CreateAppContainerProfile states that it "Creates a per-user, per-app profile for Windows Store apps" so I assumed it only applied to app store applications.

Comment: main use [PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_SECURITY_CAPABILITIES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686880(v=vs.85).aspx) - `If this attribute is set the new process will be created as an AppContainer process.`